# LodePng 24bit RGB mode can't understand how to choose

Tags: png, rgb, yuv

I have an YUV 420 (144x176) file from which I read first frame and converted its YUV components to RGB array `int rgb[HEIGHT*WIDTH*3];` in which I store R1G1B1...RnGnBn and have an `std::vector<unsigned char> image; image.resize(width * height * 4);`. My question is:
When I use `unsigned error = lodepng::encode(filename, image, width, height);` it processes without errors and generates a PNG file, but this file is not even looks like an original image, I think that it uses RGBA while I only have RGB, how to fix it?

P.S. Don't know is this ^ information is enough, so tell me if no, please.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this question should be closed now.
All I've done is added 255 as Alpha in 4th position, something like this:

```
if (i%3==0 && i != 0)
            image[k++] = 255;
        image[k] = rgb[i];
```

P.S. Another important thing I missed is to put pixels at their real position when reading from YUV file, I mean like shown on Wiki's figure. Note this if you will have problems with YUV.